# Updating existing SPA project on production (Maintenance mode?)

Tags: frontend, web-deployment, production-environment, production

I have an existing project which is live on some production server. There are a few users almost every time.

Front-end part is a SPA application (it's important)

On backend we have Maintenance mode which we are enable when we want to push our new features (it's bad because now we have a possibility to reach 0-downtime but it doesn't matter)

My question is: Which is the most correct way to do front-end production updating?

1) should we just remove old files and copy the new files to the production folder? (but in this case users might click on some link and the OLD BUNDLE will be fetched from server and we receive 404. Isn't it?)

2) Should we return some Notification Page (eg. Maintenance. Please visit our site later)  while this process is running?

What alternatives exist?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Spin up a new instance/container with the changes and point DNS at it? It's really hard to answer this without more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jared.Currently we don't have this possibility because we don't have containerized env yet. Sorry. We have just Nginx and Apache

Comment: I imagine there's a way with nginx much like apache to change the document root to point at a different directory with the changes. That way you can always change it right back if something breaks. 'Most correct' is going to depend a lot on your system architecture/level of expertise/$$$$ but the important things are to make sure you can get back to last known good easily and ideally roll out the change gradually using e.g. your load balancer. And even if you don't containerize (and I wouldn't blame you, security is still an open question) you can virtualize, and should.

Comment: that might help. Thank you. 
Btw. If you guys have any other idea - let me know. I'll appreciate as well